# View outside list not showing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a details screen and i want to display outside the list a `Text()` view and then another `List`, but when i adding the `Text()` below and outside the `List` i can't see the view

---

**Part of my code:**

```
var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            List {
                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Text("Name: \(name)")
                })
                
                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Text("Description: \(description)")
                })
                
                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Text("Numerical Target: \(numTarget)")
                })
                
                
                Picker(selection: $numUnitIndex, label: Text("Numerical Unit: \(numUnit)")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< units.count) {
                        Text(self.units[$0]).tag($0).foregroundColor(.blue)//.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                    }
                }.pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                
                
                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Text("Start date: \(startDate)")
                })
                
                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Text("End date: \(endDate)")
                })
                
                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Text("Category: \(category)")
                })
                
                
                Spacer()
            }.onAppear() {
                setPickerValue()
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationTitle("Goal Details")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Add Step") {
                    print("Help tapped!")
                }
                
            }
            
            Text("Steps for this goal").background(Color.black).font(.system(size: 20))
            
        }
        
    }
}

struct GoalDetailsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GoalDetailsView(id: "", authorId: "", name: "", description: "", startDate: "", endDate: "", numTarget: "", numUnit: "", category: "")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're placing more that one item inside `NavigationView` you need to specify container(`VStack`/`HStack`/`ZStack`) explicitly, like this:

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        List {
            // content
        }
        
        Text("Steps for this goal").font(.system(size: 20))
    }
}
```

Generally speaking, screen will be split into sections for each `NavigationView` sibling up to a system specific limit. For iOS this limit is 1, which makes all other views disappear, on iPadOS and macOS the limit is higher

Comment: More specifically, this `Text` view would otherwise only be seen on something like an iPad - with the `List` seen in the left sidebar, and the `Text` as the main content.

Comment: @George thanks, added this information to my answer

Comment: Nice. I believe it's by size classes (compact vs regular) rather than OS